# Capturing map from wikimapia.org with PhantomJS results in Parse Error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have read few posts on this topic, but they are not very specific to my need. Thats why i am asking. I am using linux with phantomjs installed.

I have a wikimapia.org (maps site similar to google maps). I want to open the url `"http://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=13.34674&lon=74.748418&z=18&m=m"` with phantomjs. So i tried the following code `test.js`.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open("http://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=13.34674&lon=74.748418&z=18&m=m", function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(page.content);
        page.render("screen.png");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Then I run: `phantomjs test.js` Also it generated screen1.png neither shows the desired map, instead shows a loading icon. There is also an error shown:

```
SyntaxError: Parse error
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ns.Utils')
```

Comment: So you want to completely embed the map in the html file so that it can load even if you have no internet connection? If yes, I don't think this is possible. To take a screenshot use `page.render("screen.png")`

Comment: I have edited my script with your code added, at two locations. Neither pngs shows the map.

Comment: I wanted to save the map. if it is not possible i am also fine with the image.

Comment: I tried your code. Please see the edited question. is the syntax right. becuase it shows the loading circular image

Comment: can you try out and if you get the image with map please let me know.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Parse error` and `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ns.Utils')` are the two errors it gives.

Answer (score 0):

The current PhantomJS (1.9.7) is an old fork for QtWebkit which is comparable to Chrome 13 or Safari 5. It means that some script cannot be evaluated with it.

In particular, the script http://wikimapia.org/js/application.js?601 cannot be parsed. This is main application, so the complete map won't work.

You can use [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) which has the same API as PhantomJS, but uses the Gecko (Firefox) engine. I've tried it and it works with a higher timeout (30 sec).

Saving the computed source won't get you the actual saved page in offline mode, because of the way the map is presented and rendered. The best that you can do is, taking a screenshot with `page.render`.